# Catch is not a function odoo

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

why am I returning a `Uncaught TypeError: creacteAccount(...).then(...).catch is not a function`? 
 Is .catch() is unacceptable? Please bear with me since I am new with these technologies :)

```
function creacteAccount(db_name, contact, email) {
    if (!(db_name > "" && contact > "" && email > "")) {
        return Promise.reject("One of the parameters is empty");
    }
    return session.rpc('/custom/createdb', {db_name: db_name})                  
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Database created successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/initdb', {db_name: db_name});           
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("Database initialized successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/installapps', {db_name: db_name});      
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("Apps installed successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/createaccount', {                      
                db_name : db_name, 
                contact_name: contact, 
                email_from: email
            });
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("User account created successfully");
        });
}

creacteAccount(db_name, contact, email).then(function () {
    console.log("Successfully creating your account")
}).catch(function (err) {
    alert("Could not create account! (" + err + ")");
});
```

This is the logs: https://jpst.it/2p-nG

Comment: Do `console.log(creacteAccount(db_name, contact, email))` and see if there is `.catch` function

Comment: If you use some older version, maybe it's `.fail`: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-this-rpc-then-fail-is-not-a-function-169929

Comment: Hi @Justinas, this is what it says here in console `web.assets_frontend.js:117 [object Object]- createAccount data
`

Comment: I use the .fail but it only read the first instance and then redirect to another page. It doesn't finish the process of every instance.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works

Comment: May I know what did I wrong? Your opinion is greatly appreciated :)


What I wanted to achieve is this and making sure that every instances finishes its job before proceeding to another instances:

Scenario:
First instance // first called
Sec instance // next called then
Third instance // next called then
Fourth instance // last called

Comment: I would manually call each instance processing: `.finally(() => callAnotherInstance())`

Comment: do you have any examples? so that I can do it on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I have never used odoo